# cloud foundry eclipse plugin repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nexus, cloud-foundry, springsource

My company uses Nexus Pro for Artifacts and Plug-ins.  Our Nexus instance has access through our firewall so that our developers don't need it.  The down side to this is that the Eclipse Market Place doesn't work.  In the past we have found P2 repositories that can be setup as a proxy P2 repository.

Does a P2 repository exist that I can link to so I can get Cloud Foundry from SpringSource?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the p2 repository where you can get the Cloud Foundry for Eclipse tooling from:

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/cloudfoundry

This refers to the last version from the old Cloud Foundry for Eclipse project. After the project moved to Eclipse, the 1.0.0.M2 version (the latest available milestone release) can be found here:

http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/cft/1.0.0.M2

Hope this helps!